# Grouping and deduping data based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, grouping, partitioning

I have a query that results in some of data being duplicated and I need to de-dupe it based on criteria that itself is based on groups.

The results I am getting look something like this on top level:

Activity Date - Source - Rating - Comment - Contact - Attended Event?

While I need all the columns, two are of key importance:

- Contact
- Source

This one should be used for main grouping:

- Attended Event? (Yes or No, already populated)

And these two should influence the deduping:

- Rating
- Activity Date

The challenge is that due to the way the data is fed into the system I might have a Contact in the resulting data that can appear multiple times and has multiple other fields populated, and I would like to capture the following:

- only one instance of a Contact per the "Attended Event?" field
- the Contact needs to be deduped based on different criteria depending on whether that field is "Yes" or "No".

I need to keep both "Yes" and "No" for each contact and I need to pull the lowest Rating for that Contact with the earliest Activity Date for that Rating.

I have been trying with no success to use the row_number () over (partition by...) approach but wondering if I am trying to do too much in a single query? Would it be better to split the queries into groups first based on the "Attended Event" column and then dedupe them?

Here is the sample query I am using. I have tried attaching some sample data but I cannot for the life of me get it to format as a table, and apparently cannot add images as I have too few points...

Query:

```
Select
Table1.activity_datetime, 
Table1.source, 
Table1.rating, 
Table1.form_comments, 
Table2.source_code, 
Table2.type, 
Table3.company, 
Table4.contact_sk,
Table5.first_name,
Table5.last_name,
Table5.email_addr,
Table5.job_title,
Table5.company,
Table5.country,
CASE when Table1.form_comments like '%Register%' then 'Registered' else 'Attended' end as 'Registered or Attended'

from [Database].[Table1] Table1
JOIN [Database].[Table4] Table4 ON Table1
JOIN [Database].[Table5] Table5 ON Table4
JOIN [Database].[Table3] Table3 ON Table5
LEFT JOIN [Database].[Table2] Table2  ON Table4
```

Comment: Please clarify your question with the addition of a [mre] i.e. include sample data, desired results and your attempt. As it is its too hard for anyone other than yourself to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi @DaleK,

Thank you for your reply. I am attaching a sample data set & query in the hopes it can make my request a bit clearer: